# How to convert date json to php

Tags: php, json, date, getjson

I have a problem receiving the date in PHP page

i send date with getJSON function from html page to php page

this code in js

```
var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
var end = moment();
    
function cb(start, end) {
    $('#reportrange span')
        .html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') 
            + ' - ' 
            + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY')
        );
}
    
$('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
    startDate: start,
    endDate: end,
    ranges: {
            'last 7 day': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
            'last 30 days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
            'this month': [moment().startOf('month'),
                            moment().endOf('month')],
            'last month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), 
                            moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
            }
        }, cb).on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
            var startDate = picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            var endDate = picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            // alert(`startDate = ${startDate}, endDate = ${endDate}`);
            
            $.getJSON("getdata.php", {startDate: startDate },function (result) {
                // your result function
                $('#data').html(result);
        });
});
    
cb(start, end);
```

I tried with the following code but it didn't work

```
if (isset($_GET['startDate'])) {
    $startDate = $_GET['startDate'];
    echo   $startDate;
    exit;
}
```

when user select rang date i want send start and end date to php page to select data between this dates.

I tried sending other data and it appears, but when sending a date it does not appear.

Comment: Ok, so if you pass a valid date in the format `'YYYY-MM-DD'` then this code will work and produce valid output !!!! So you had better do some basic debugging!! Show us what is being sent to the PHP in `$_GET['startDate'];`. Also consider showing us the JS code that does the `getJSON()`

Comment: thank you for reply i edit my post for more info.

Comment: Good code indentation and layout ___is for life, not just for Christmas___ and would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will be glad you took the time in the end.

Comment: We still dont know what you are actually passing in the `startDate` via `$_GET['startDate']`